# What are the values of Google OAuth consent screen?

Tags: google-analytics, oauth-2.0, postman

I am trying to establish a connection between POSTMAN & Google Analytics to get an access token. I have enabled all the necessary apis & I have the credentials required to do so. The one thing that I have not done yet is to verify the OAuth consent screen values. What is the value of

1. Authorized domain
2. Application Homepage link
3. Application Privacy Policy link

The OAuth consent screen requires me to add values which are similar to this:

**Authorized domain**

1. 'website_name.com' --  I am guessing that I need to put the domain name of my website in the authroized domains column.

**Application Homepage Link**

2. _____________ (must contain 'website_name' in the link). I am not sure what value I need to add here as the application that I am trying to use is POSTMAN.

The error that i get when I add 'https://www.getpostman.com/' is - Invalid domain: URL must be hosted on a domain listed in the "Authorized domains" section.

**Application Privacy Link**

3. Same error as above for the Application Privacy Link.

(One more thing that I want to mention is that I have not done Domain verification which I think should not be an issue)

I am successfully able to generate the access token from the google api explorer -   iamcredentials.projects.serviceAccounts.generateAccessToken - https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#s/iamcredentials/v1/ but when using the same way in POSTMAN it fails

Let me know if any of this is unclear or need more information and i can write in the comment section.